# Outputting text file to csv using bash

Tags: bash, csv

I am new to bash and I'm not sure how to do the following: 
I have a text file in the format:

```
123
John

234
Sally

456
Lucy

...
```

I want to output it to a csv file in the form:

```
123,John
234,Sally
456,Lucy
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good job for `sed`:

```
sed '/[0-9]/{N;s/\n/,/}' txtfile
```

It detects lines having numbers and, when found, replaces the newline character by a comma.

If you also want to get rid of the blank lines in-between,

```
sed '/[0-9]/{N;s/\n/,/;n;d}' txtfile
```

Notice that if your file is as regular as the sample you gave, you don't even need the regex, `'N;s/\n/,/;n;d'` would suffice.